# Duplicate data being stored into database

Tags: python, duplicates, psycopg2, raspberry-pi

I'm winding up with duplicate entries into a database when I run my script and I was wondering what I might be doing wrong.

**Hardware**
I've got an instrument connected to my Raspberry Pi via serial communication at 115,200.  The instrument outputs a line of data every second and I'd like to store this data into the database.  Each line is terminated with a \n.

**Software**
Python 2.7.3rc2
PySerial
PostgreSQL 9.1
Debian Wheezy

The database has one table called wattsup which I created:

```
CREATE TABLE wattsup (
    wattsuplocation text
    wattsuptime timestamp
    wattsupvalue numeric
);
```

My Python script looks like:

```
import serial
import time
import psycopg2

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200)
Location = 'A'

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='mydb' user='thotchi'")
cur = conn.cursor()

Insert = "INSERT INTO wattsup (wattsuplocation, wattsuptime, wattsupvalue) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"

while 1:
    line = ser.readline()

    DataArray = line.split(',') #CSV output

    if len(DataArray) != 21:
        continue
    else:
        Time = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        Watts = float(DataArray[3]) / 10
        cur.execute(Insert, (Location, Time, Watts))
        conn.commit()
```

It generally works but I get some duplicates in data that I don't understand.  When I query the database, I can find data like.

```
A, 2012-11-04 18:00:00, 5.0
A, 2012-11-04 18:00:01, 5.1
A, 2012-11-04 18:00:02, 5.0
A, 2012-11-04 18:00:03, 4.9
A, 2012-11-04 18:00:04, 5.0
A, 2012-11-04 18:00:05, 5.0
A, 2012-11-04 18:00:05, 5.0
A, 2012-11-04 18:00:05, 5.0
A, 2012-11-04 18:00:05, 5.0
A, 2012-11-04 18:00:06, 5.1
```

Notice that there are duplicate data (A, 2012-11-04 18:00:05, 5.0).  I know the instrument only outputs data at 1 second so I'm am certain it's not the instrument.  I tried changing the code some so that the commit occurs every 10 entries which seemed to improve the situation.

Any idea what might be going on?  I'm stumped.

Thanks!

Comment: The pi doesn't have a 'real' clock, so that is one possibility.  Are you overclocking? (Not sure if it matters, but could be another source of a timing issue)  Record milliseconds to see if the records are still duplicates

Comment: Where's the part that says the table has a primary key that forbids rows to be duplicates?

Comment: Hi shaun5 and hughbrown: Interesting thoughts, thanks! So I tried a few things based on your suggestions. 1. Got rid of the database portion altogether since I don't know what I'm doing there anyway and replaced it with a print statement. 2. I printed datetime.datetime.now() and indeed, the timestamps are different by about 0.05 seconds. 3. I added a `timeout=None` option to `ser` because I really do want this thing to hang until I get a full line. Still no resolution. I did notice that when I get the duplicates, it prints them really quickly in succession after it pauses for a while.

Comment: The 4th thing I tried was running this same script on my windows XP machine and then it seems to work fine.  It seems to use an extraordinary amount of processor time on the Raspberry Pi.  I'll have to investigate this some more.

Comment: Before `line.split`, try dumping the line length and line content (in hex) to verify what's coming in.

Comment: @mike, that exceeds my understanding but thanks for the lead.  I'll snoop around and try learning about hex and will report back.

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas
1) You can add some wait statement to the while loop. Now it is running the loop and using all the processor time
2) You are using a Serial to USB converter and these devices sometimes buffer the data. 
3) The onboard UART also buffers the data
4) When doing a Readline, it depends on what as used as the termination character: Cr, LF or CrLF
5) You can try and use Read and then read into your own string buffer and look for the first terminator.